# Machine Learning Approach for Aerodynamic Design?

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to ML so please excuse my ignorance. I am trying to use machine learning to enhance the design of turbomachinery components. Traditionally, a component such as a compressor is parameterized via maybe 30 or so parameters and then these parameters are tuned by hand using an iterative process involving computational fluid dynamics (CFD) to evaluate potential designs. The engineer uses his/her judgment to guide the design until it is satisfactory with regard to efficiency, stress etc. Essentially the engineer is trying to find the best combination of the input variables.

This process is quite tedious when done by hand, and I would like to develop a machine learning tool to speed it up. An optimization routine could be used, and I have done this, but then it would require successive, expensive design evaluations to optimize the design. I would like to train an ML model produce an ‘optimal design’ without expensive iterations. I am OK with an expensive training phase.

Essentially I would like the computer to act as an engineer would: take the state of the surroundings (the complete fluid dynamic information from a CFD simulation) and adjust the design variables until an ‘optimal’ solution is found.

Essentially, I just want the best combination of all variables. Any thoughts on what ML strategy I should consider?

I initially thought reinforcement learning would be a good fit, but all the examples I can see seem to have a time element, that is the changes in the inputs need to be done in a certain order. For my problem, there is no order, the results have no memory.

Maybe a GP surrogate model would be good? But I would like the tool to develop a generalized strategy for when it sees this type of flow structure to make this type of change to the geometry. I am not sure a GP surrogate model could do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello, Kevin! Can you elaborate on the nature and amount of data that you have?

Comment: We don't have any quite yet. Part of the project will be to generate the training data. When I was thinking about this project I figured we would be running a whole lot of these cases to generate the training data (my initial estimate was 1 million cases but that was a wild guess). Also, 30 parameters is an estimate, it could be 15 or 50 depending on how its parameterized. The geometry is represented as a series of bsplines and we can choose the number of control points.

Comment: All that a trained model will be able to do is capture a general idea of how the simulation behaves _within the distribution that was fed to it_, so you will definitely shift your problem into an entirely new problem landscape, which will inevitably be a distortion of the original one. Since your current optimization process is more-or-less manual and involves running simulations to evaluate the overall suitability of parameters, you might benefit from employing various metaheuristics to guide your search. A probabilistic model will never predict better than a simulation with same input.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, what do you mean by metaheuristic?

Comment: You're welcome! Metaheuristics are special techniques that help find a "good enough" solution for any type of optimization problem, regardless of domain. I'll try to formulate a structured and coherent answer with some practical suggestions over the weekend.